# Is there a way to add a single newline at the end of the output?

Tags: java, printing, format, newline

```
public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
       int userNum=in.nextInt();
       int divNum=in.nextInt();
       int i=0;
       while(i<3){
       userNum=userNum/divNum;
       if(userNum==0);
   System.out.print(userNum+""+"\n");
   i++;
   }
   }
}
```

This results in an output formatted like this,

```
1000 
500 
250
```

Output is nearly correct; but whitespace differs. See highlights below.

```
Special character legend
Input
2000 2
Your output
1000 
500 
250 
Expected output
1000 500 250
```

I want it to be like this 1000 500 250 (newline here)

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please provide more context. I'm guessing this is in a loop? How have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I assume you are running that print statement in a loop, because otherwise i don't quite get how you would get your supposed current output. If that is the case just do `System.out.print( "\r\n");` once after your loop is done with his printing

Comment: Also, this seems to be about java, not javascript - please don't add unrelated language tags.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe let's try this one:

```
System.out.print(userNum + " ");
```

And at the end use this:

```
System.out.println();
```

or

```
System.out.print("\n");
```

This will add you a newline :)

Comment: same result,
 1000 newline
500 newline
250 newline
expected output is 1000 500 250 newline

Comment: Hmm... that's weird :-/ That should be because of other part of the code I guess. Here everything should be fine.

Comment: Here is the rest of my code import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
       int userNum=in.nextInt();
       int divNum=in.nextInt();
       int i=0;
       while(i<3){
       userNum=userNum/divNum;
       if(userNum==0)
       break;

Comment: I tried your code with my earlier fix and it worked fine. There must be something wrong in other place than your code I guess :-/

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
System.out.println(userNum);
```

Comment: Output is nearly correct; but whitespace differs. See highlights below.  
Special character legend
Input
2000 2
Your output
1000 newline
500 newline
250 extra whitespace
Expected output
1000 500 250